# How to sum up the weights of equall rows of a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a (m x n) matrix. each row has its own weight, I should find the rows which are equal and sum up their related weights. 
I really appreciate it if you could help me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: do you have 2 matrices one which you want to compare (if theyare equal) and another with the corresponding weights? or do you want to use standard-error, or standard deviation or any other means to compute the weights? And what do you mean with "sum up their related weights". Do you want to just add them. like row a,b,f are equal so you get `new_weight=weight_a+weight_b+weight_f`?

Comment: @JeroenvanderHooft Though an example of inputs and desired outputs would definitely be helpfull, it is not reasonable to ask for a working example here as the asker is essentially looking for that.

Comment: No, I have just one matrix with m (for example, 256) rows and n (for example, 6) columns. All the elements are 0 or 1. each row has a weight (for example, 0.2) which is calculated through some formula based on that row's elements. Consider this case that there are 64 different rows, each of these rows are repeated 4 times in the matrix with 256 rows. I should find the index of equal rows then using that index I can find that row's weight and sum up the equal rows' weights.

Comment: A simple example is like this, 'A' is the matrix. I have a vector of weights for each row. A= [ 0 0 0 ; 1 0 0 ; 0 1 0 ; 0 0 1 ; 0 0 0 ; 0 0 1 ];  weights = [ 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.9, 0.7]; I should find that the first row is equal to 5th row then I can sum up their related weights. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a matrix and vector of weights:

```
M = rand(m,n);
W = rand(1,n);
```

Then you can start by getting all unique rows of the matrix:

```
U = unique(M,'rows')
```

From here it is just a small step to get the relevant weights for each unique row, so I will leave that as an excercise.

Comment: @Davoud Also, the _third_ output of `unique` may be even more useful

Comment: i think unique is the wrong approch. Better show him logical indexing(edit: or as Luis Mendo pointed out show him the third output), after all he wants to find all non unique rows, or better all rows that are equal... but +1 for leaving the rest as an exercise

Comment: @TheMinion I think `unique` is quite right if you use its _third_ output as first input to `accumarray`

Comment: @LuisMendo you are right. Just edited my comment. I completely forgot about that third output.

Comment: I should find the indices of equal rows, then, I can sum up the weights of those equal rows. Can I find the equal rows' indices using  unique? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Davoud It was already hinted in the comments, but check out this example: `[u,ia,ic]=unique([5;6;7;6])`